# Why migrations is not working neither it creates migrations directory in django app

Tags: django

It was working fine I first installed the app. After that i deleted my `db.sqlite` `migrations` and `pycache` file. Then I tried to migrate again all the default migrations worked except for the Post model which is in the postapp. I tried several time to migrate, every time it says no change detected and doesn't create any migrations directory

after running `python manage.py showmigrations` I get something like this it does not mentions post app name or any migrations related to post app

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

How can I solve this it happens to me in every Django project. it needs to  be fixed

Comment: Why did you delete the cache and migration files?

Comment: @panatale1 I have to I added slug field and category field so I thought its better to delete them start them again.

Comment: you should have just added the fields and made an additional migration

Comment: @panatale1 I did that but to run additional migrations I need to put some value in the posts that I have created that's what I don't want to do. So anyway my problem is fixed. I just made separate migrations it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either run the migration commands mentioning the particular app, for example:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py migrate <app_name>
```

Then it will create the migrations file inside the app directory.

**Or** you need to create a `migrations` folder inside the app directory, and put a `__init__.py` file inside it. Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` command.

BTW, why do you need to delete migration files? Its best to keep the migration files and commit them to your repository if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Django` keeps track of all migrations in `django_migration` table. you can reinitiate all migration of app by

`python manage.py migrate <APP_NAME> zero`